# log4j2 with Mongodb issue logging throwable with message

Tags: java, mongodb, log4j2

I'm trying to setup log4j2 with mongoDb3 and everything works fine, only problem is when I long throwable exception with message something like this

```
logger.error("Some Message",new Exception("Test"));
```

I will get an error as

```
Caused by: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.apache.logging.log4j.mongodb3.MongoDbDocumentObject.
```

but I can easily log error with

```
 logger.error(new Exception("Test"));
```

without any issue.

Our project is using slf4j mainly for logging and all of our error logs styled like the first example.
is there any way I can fix this error without changing all the exception logs?

Also my config is fairly simple

```
<NoSql name="databaseAppender">
    <MongoDb3 databaseName="admin" collectionName="testLogger" server="localhost"
              username="***" password="****" />
</NoSql>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After lot's of headache and testing I figured out how to solve this problem.
I just post my result here incase someone else ran into this issue.

For some reason `org.apache.logging.log4j.mongodb3.MongoDbDocumentObject` is not getting register by MongoDb codecs automatically so I have to create a ConnectionFactory class to register the class .

```
    public static MongoClient getMongoClient () {
    MongoClientOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = MongoClientOptions.builder()
            .codecRegistry(CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                    CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new LevelCodec()),
                    CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().register(MongoDbDocumentObject.class).build()),
                    MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry()));

    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://"+userName+":"+passWord+"@"+dbUrl+":"+port,optionsBuilder);
    return new MongoClient(uri);
}
```

Obviously you have to change your log4j Appender to use the class and method :

```
 <NoSql name="databaseAppender">
            <MongoDb3 databaseName="test" collectionName="testLogger" factoryClassName="ClassName"
                      factoryMethodName="getMongoClient" />
        </NoSql>
```

My dependancies are :

```
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'
// Log4j
implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.13.3'
implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name:'log4j-mongodb3', version:'2.13.3'
implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.13.3'
implementation  group:'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat',name:'jackson-dataformat-xml', version:'2.9.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver
implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.12.7'
```